# asignar href seleccionado a una variable php

Tags: php

la siguiente funcion lo que hace es buscar una palabra digitada y me muestra las posibles coincidencias (buscador). Cuando me muestra las coincidencias lo estoy haciendo a traves de un href y quisiera almacenar el href en una variable php, para ir guardando las búsquedas que se realizan. Mi idea es utilizar las opciones donde el usuario de click, pero pueden ser varias opciones no solo es una.

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_POST['search'])) exit('No se recibió el valor a buscar');

require_once 'conexion.php';

function search()
{
  $mysqli = getConnexion();
  $search = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
  $query = "SELECT sintomas_resp FROM sintomas WHERE sintomas_resp LIKE '%$search%' ";
  $res = $mysqli->query($query);
  while ($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<p><a href='#'>$row[sintomas_resp]</a></p>";
  }
}

search();
```

Comment: ¿Cual es tu consulta? ¿Qué te falla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo tienes que declarar la variable fuera del while y así imprimir-la al acabar...

```html
<?php 
if(!isset($_POST['search'])) exit('No se recibió el valor a buscar');

require_once 'conexion.php';

function search()
{
  $mysqli = getConnexion();
  $search = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
  $query = "SELECT sintomas_resp FROM sintomas WHERE sintomas_resp LIKE '%$search%' ";
  $res = $mysqli->query($query);
  $Listado = "";
  while ($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $Listado = $Liestado . "<p><a href='#'>$row[sintomas_resp]</a></p>";
  }
  echo ($Listado); 
}

search();
```